# Plotting dynamic treatment effects using marginaleffects package in R

Tags: r, r-marginaleffects

I am attempting to use the `marginaleffects` package in R to plot the effect of treatment on the outcome across time (i.e., dynamic treatment effects). My data consists of two groups (treated and control), seven time points, and a continuous outcome.

```
library(tibble)

d <- tibble(id = rep(1:10, each = 7),
            periods = factor(rep(0:6, times = 10)),
            treated = factor(ifelse(id<=5, 1, 0)),
            y = ifelse(treated==1, rnorm(100, 2, 0.5), rnorm(100, 0, 1)))

head(d, n=10)
# A tibble: 10 × 4
      id periods treated     y
   <int> <fct>   <fct>   <dbl>
 1     1 0       1        2.31
 2     1 1       1        2.32
 3     1 2       1        2.16
 4     1 3       1        1.74
 5     1 4       1        1.93
 6     1 5       1        2.17
 7     1 6       1        2.25
 8     2 0       1        2.02
 9     2 1       1        1.90
10     2 2       1        2.50
```

To fit the model, I used a standard two-way fixed-effects DiD approach where there are fixed effects for time (`periods` in my case) and group (`treated` in my case), and the treatment effect is represented by the interaction of the two (`treated`*`periods`).

In the model output (printed below), I am interested in plotting the effects for the `treated*:periods*` terms--which represent the effect of treatment across time after accounting for the group and time fixed effects.

```
# fit model
m <- lm(y ~ treated*periods, data = d)

# print model output
tidy(m, conf.int = TRUE)

# A tibble: 14 × 7
   term              estimate std.error statistic   p.value conf.low conf.high
   <chr>                <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 (Intercept)         0.269      0.308    0.872  0.387       -0.349     0.887
 2 treated1            2.11       0.436    4.84   0.0000107    1.24      2.98 
 3 periods1            0.475      0.436    1.09   0.281       -0.399     1.35 
 4 periods2           -0.0516     0.436   -0.118  0.906       -0.925     0.822
 5 periods3           -0.343      0.436   -0.787  0.435       -1.22      0.531
 6 periods4            0.0433     0.436    0.0994 0.921       -0.831     0.917
 7 periods5            0.578      0.436    1.33   0.190       -0.296     1.45 
 8 periods6           -0.220      0.436   -0.504  0.616       -1.09      0.654
 9 treated1:periods1  -1.07       0.617   -1.73   0.0897      -2.30      0.171
10 treated1:periods2   0.171      0.617    0.277  0.783       -1.07      1.41 
11 treated1:periods3   0.0223     0.617    0.0361 0.971       -1.21      1.26 
12 treated1:periods4  -0.635      0.617   -1.03   0.308       -1.87      0.601
13 treated1:periods5  -0.966      0.617   -1.57   0.123       -2.20      0.270
14 treated1:periods6  -0.170      0.617   -0.275  0.784       -1.41      1.07
```

However, when I attempt to plot the treatment effects using `marginaleffects`, the plotted values do not match the treatment effects from the model output (the `treated*:periods*` terms). I included the output of the call to `avg_comparisons()` rather than `plot_comparisons()` below for ease of reference:

```
library(marginaleffects)

avg_comparisons(m, variables = "treated", by = "periods")

    Term          Contrast periods Estimate Std. Error    z Pr(>|z|)    S 2.5 % 97.5 %
 treated mean(1) - mean(0)       0     2.11      0.436 4.84  < 0.001 19.5  1.26   2.97
 treated mean(1) - mean(0)       1     1.05      0.436 2.40  0.01657  5.9  0.19   1.90
 treated mean(1) - mean(0)       2     2.28      0.436 5.23  < 0.001 22.5  1.43   3.14
 treated mean(1) - mean(0)       3     2.13      0.436 4.89  < 0.001 19.9  1.28   2.99
 treated mean(1) - mean(0)       4     1.48      0.436 3.38  < 0.001 10.4  0.62   2.33
 treated mean(1) - mean(0)       5     1.14      0.436 2.62  0.00868  6.8  0.29   2.00
 treated mean(1) - mean(0)       6     1.94      0.436 4.45  < 0.001 16.8  1.09   2.80
```

It looks to me like `avg_comparisons()` is not taking the fixed effects into account when estimating the comparisons between the groups over time. How do I obtain `avg_comparisons()` or `plot_comparisons()` that match the treatment effects contained in the model output (`treated*:periods*`)?

I have attempted numerous variants of this call `avg_comparisons(m, variables = c("periods", "treated"), by = "treated")`, including switching which terms are included in the call to `variables` and which variables are included in the call to `by`. But none of them produce the output I am looking for.

I have also attempted `avg_comparisons(m, variables = "treated:periods")` to obtain the interaction effect, but this produced the error: `Error: There is no valid predictor variable. Please change the` variables `argument or supply a new data frame to the 'newdata' argument.`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misinterpreting your model coefficients and that `avg_comparisons()` correctly reports the quantities of interest.

Consider this code, where I set a seed for replicability:

```r
library(tibble)
library(marginaleffects)
set.seed(1024)

d <- tibble(
  id = rep(1:10, each = 7),
  periods = rep(0:6, times = 10),
  treated = ifelse(id <= 5, 1, 0),
  y = ifelse(treated == 1, rnorm(100, 2, 0.5), rnorm(100, 0, 1)))

m <- lm(y ~ factor(treated) * factor(periods), data = d)
```

Estimate the average difference in predicted outcome between the treated and control groups, at different periods:

```r
e <- avg_comparisons(m, variables = "treated", by = "periods")
```

First, note that the “effect” of a change from 0 to 1 in the `treated` variable in period 2 is *not* equal to just the interaction term. It is equal to the sum of these two coefficients:

```r
coef(m)["factor(treated)1"] + coef(m)["factor(treated)1:factor(periods)2"]
# factor(treated)1 
#         2.153658
```

This can be verified using the `predict()` function from base R. See what happens to the predicted outcome when `treated` goes from 0 to 1, for different periods: 0 and 2.

```r
d0 <- data.frame(treated = 0, periods = 0)
d1 <- data.frame(treated = 1, periods = 0)
p0 <- predict(m, newdata = d0)
p1 <- predict(m, newdata = d1)
p1 - p0
#        1 
# 2.792739

d0 <- data.frame(treated = 0, periods = 2)
d1 <- data.frame(treated = 1, periods = 2)
p0 <- predict(m, newdata = d0)
p1 <- predict(m, newdata = d1)
p1 - p0
#        1 
# 2.153658
```

Finally, see that these are exactly the results that `avg_comparisons()` reports:

```r
subset(e, periods %in% c(0, 2))
# 
#     Term          Contrast Estimate Std. Error    z Pr(>|z|)    S CI low
#  treated mean(1) - mean(0)     2.79      0.578 4.83   <0.001 19.5   1.66
#  treated mean(1) - mean(0)     2.15      0.578 3.72   <0.001 12.3   1.02
#  CI high
#     3.93
#     3.29
# 
# Columns: term, contrast, periods, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high, predicted_lo, predicted_hi, predicted
```

Comment: thanks @Vincent for the quick response (and thanks for all your work developing the `marginaleffects` package!). Completely possible that I'm misunderstanding something, but I believe the interaction effects **are** capturing the treatment effects. In this case, the treatment effect(s) is the difference between the treatment group's actual trajectory and their "counterfactual" trajectory--which is _the trajectory that the treatment group would've had if they were like the control group_.
See [here](https://ds4ps.org/pe4ps-textbook/docs/p-030-diff-in-diff.html) for a nice illustration

Comment: Here, I think `avg_comparisons(m, variables = "treated", by = "periods")` is calculating the difference between the treated group and the control group. But what I really need (at each time point) is the difference between the treated group and the _counterfactual_ group. Perhaps I need to make use of a counterfactual dataset? I've read through the `marginaleffects` section on [Causal Inference](https://marginaleffects.com/articles/gformula.html), but I wasn't sure if this was the correct approach or, if so, how to implement it in this case

Comment: What do you mean *specifically* by "counterfactual group"? My code block with `predict()` shows that `avg_comparisons()` is equivalent to creating counterfactual datasets (`d0`, `d1`) and computing the difference in predictions between them. `avg_comparisons()` does a counterfactual analysis! If you want to only consider these kinds of counterfactual comparisons in the subset of treated observations, you can add an additional argument to define the grid: `newdata=subset(d,treated==1)`. You'll get the same result here, but it will differ in non-linear models or with more covariates.